# How to add option using MultiSelect jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using the jQuery - MultiSelect plugin.

I want to be able to add an option to my initial select box, and then have the MultiSelect user interface update with the new option.

Here is what I have (which doesn't work).

```
var value = $("#newGroup").val();
$('#Select1').append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>");
```

Then I've tried to call the same code to recreate the multiselect along with other options like destroying it first.

Here is the code I use to implement the plugin.

```
$("#Select1").multiselect({ sortable: false, searchable: true });
```

Here is the plugin's home page:
http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/

Answer (score 21):

Do you have the latest version of MultiSelect? Version 1.8 now adds a refresh command that is designed to update lists to reflect newly appended or deleted options. Your code sequence should be:

```
var value = $("#newGroup").val();
$('#Select1').append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>");
$('#Select1').multiselect( 'refresh' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As this question is over a year old, I am no longer working on this problem.  No idea if what you have will work or not and can't test!  Hopefully this helps others that may stumble on this and the up votes will be your reward if this works!

Comment: Thanks for the 'refresh', it's also useful when you want to select them all with:`$('#selcVar option').each(function() {$(this).prop('selected', true);});
$('#selcVar').multiselect( 'refresh' );`

Comment: I have a version with multiSelect with a capital S please consider adding edit.

Answer (score 5):

try to use

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect('destroy');
$('.multiselect').multiselect();
```

Comment: I had tried this.  Had an error: 
$.widget.prototype.destroy is undefined

I fixed it after a search online, but then the $('.multiselect').multiselect(); the listbox stays plain.  The "new" look does not re-apply.

Comment: I think it should be like this in your case:  $('#Select1').multiselect('destroy');
$('#Select1').multiselect();

Comment: Just so we are clear, using Select1, I was getting the above issues.

Comment: I was looking for a solution like this, refresh didn't work but using destroy and then creating the multiselect works and it maintains the state of the elements I had added or removed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For old versions you can try this

```
$('select').multiselect('destroy').removeData().multiselect();
```

'destroy' method doesn't remove data from the select node so when you try to initialize it again it thinks that it already initialized. removeData() solves the problem.

New versions has 'refresh' method so you can append some options to the select and call

```
$('select').multiselect('refresh');
```

when multiselect already initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Even i was stuck into something like this means when i appended the option into select after that it wasn't updating the multiselect so i got this below solution.

```
$('#Select1').append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>");
```

After this add this line.

```
$('#Select1').multiselect('rebuild');
```

And it will rebuild the multiselect with the newest data added also.