# How to reinitialize a function in jQuery after having modified the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, multi-select

Using a jQuery Plugin ([Link to Plugin Code](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multiple-Select-With-Checkboxes-multi-select-js.html)) I try to achieve a multi-select drop-down menu. Then I want to dynamically (depending on user input) change the menu-entries. The first part works fine, but changing menu-entries doesn't so far. Therefor I wanted to ask for help.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<select id="Fruits" name="Fruits" multiple="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Number1</option>
    <option value="2">Number2</option>
    <option value="3">Number3</option>
</select>
```

Then I use that code to initialise the menu:

```
$(function(){
   $('#Fruits').multiSelect({'noneText':'Select Fruits'});
});
```

The result is precisely what I want:

[image: Menu Fruits]

Next I try to dynamically add a menu-entry. I do that by the following code:

```
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = "Number4";
   option.value = "4";
   var select = document.getElementById("Fruits");
   select.appendChild(option);
```

This is what I hope to achieve:
[image: Menu Fruits with appended option]

However the result looks precisely like the first picture. Also running

```
$(function(){
   $('#Fruits').multiSelect({'noneText':'Select Fruits'});
});
```

again doesn't help.

Comment: `$('#Fruits').multiselect( 'refresh' );`I think this will help you understand it better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459974/how-to-add-option-using-multiselect-jquery-plugin

Comment: @angel.bonev Why do you think they (`.multiselect()` and `.multiSelect()`) are the same?

Comment: @Andreas you're rigth sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `MultiSelect` instance (`.data("plugin_multiSelect")`) from the `<select>` and call `.updateMenuItems()` after you've added the new elements:

```js
$("select").data("plugin_multiSelect")
           .updateMenuItems();
```

--
The answer is based on the [source code](https://github.com/mysociety/jquery-multi-select) and a test on their [demo page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multiple-Select-With-Checkboxes-multi-select-js/).